# Confusing equivalence $\Phi(n,n)\downarrow \Leftrightarrow \text{HALT}(n,n)$

Tags: computability, halting-problem

Let $B$ be a recursive enumerable set and $B = W_n$, where $W_n = \{x \in \mathbb N \mid \Phi(x,n)\downarrow\}$ and $\Phi^{(n)}(x_1, \ldots, x_n, y)$ is the value of the function at the terminal snaphot.

There is a definition that leaves me really confused:
$$n \in W_n \Leftrightarrow \Phi(n,n)\downarrow \Leftrightarrow \text{HALT}(n,n)$$

the thing is we know that $\text{HALT}$ is not computable, therefore is is *undefined* so how is it possible that it is equivalent to $\Phi(n,n)\downarrow$ which is actually a defined function? What am I missing here?

Comment: A function may be defined but not computable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function HALT is perfectly defined, it's just not computable - there is no program that computes it. Similarly, $\Phi(n,n) \downarrow$ is not a condition that can be computed by a program. The situation is asymmetric: if $\Phi(n,n) \downarrow$ then a program can verify that, but in the other case you're at loss. This is because HALT is recursively enumerable (partially computable).

Comment: Basically the equivalence expresses the impossibility to check with an algorithm whether a program will eventually stop, which is definition for HALT. — I apologize in advance, here it comes the dumb question. — So if $\Phi(n,n) \downarrow$ is defined so is $\text{HALT}(n,n)$ and they are both true. But doesn't it also mean that $\Phi(n,n)$ computes $\text{HALT}(n,n)$? (I know the answer is no, but can't see the underlying reason.)

Comment: It's true that $\Phi(n,n)$ partially computes $\mathrm{HALT}(n,n)$. The problem is that to know whether $\mathrm{HALT}(n,n)$ is true or not, you need to wait for $\Phi(n,n)$ to (possibly) terminate, and you cannot foresee in advance how long you should be waiting. A program $P$ computes a predicate $Q$ if $P(x)$ *always* halts and returns the truth value of $Q(x)$. In contrast, $\Phi(n,n)$ doesn't always halt.